# middleman - asset path for CDN at build time

Tags: ruby, sprockets, middleman

I want to do the following

```
if build?
    assetPath = "//cdn.domain.com/assets"
else
    assetPath = "assets"
end
```

trying all combinations and reading everywhere but simply stumped at the moment

ruby and middleman - still learning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying this within the `config.rb`? If not, you should do so.

There already is a setting that you might want to use ...

```
set :css_dir, 'assets'
```

... and change on build:

```
configure :build do
  set :css_dir, '//cdn.domain.com/assets'
end
```

Are you aware of the [Asset helpers](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/helpers/#asset-helpers)? You can use ...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'foo.css' %>
```

... within your (ERB) templates.

While developing that should give you ...

```
<link href="/assets/foo.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

... and within your build:

```
<link href="//cdn.domain.com/assets/foo.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hi I am sure I tried all of this - maybe some other issues with the setup is colliding - I will try again thanks

Comment: I have been looking for a solution involving http_prefix for CDN usage, finding nothing but a lot of frustration! This solution worked great for me, thanks.

Comment: This solution does not work when combined with the asset_hash option. You must use the asset_host option to set a cdn url as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had problems with the early answer.  To actually change the asset path to work with CDNs such as CloudFront, I had to do the following:

```
# Fingerprint assets
activate :asset_hash

# Enable Asset Hosts
activate :asset_host

set :asset_host do |asset|
  '//d23xxk856.cloudfront.net'.to_s
end
```

Comment: Do you really need that .to_s ? Seems redundant as you're turning a string into a string.

Comment: For what it's worth, this syntax is no longer correct. https://middlemanapp.com/basics/build_and_deploy